# How to find connected components in graph with Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, graph, libraries, graph-algorithm

What is the easiest way to find connected components of graph? **Not strongly connected components** which can be found with `TSort` module.

There is a library `RGL` which has a method in module `RGL::Graph::each_connected_component` but how to build a graph and call this method for this graph?

I have created sample graph like

```
g = RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph[1,2, 2,3, 4,5]
```

and want to find it's connected components, which are [[1,2,3],[4,5]] but there is no method `each_connected_component` in `g`

```
class RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph
  include RGL::Graph
end
```

did not help.

Comment: The gem has documentation: http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/index.html - have you read it? If so, could you explain, using some code snippets, where you are stuck?

Comment: I have created graph with `RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph.new` and dont know  what to do next with it.

Comment: It seems you may just need to `require 'rgl/connected_components'` However, `each_connected_component` only works for undirected graphs. Do you need a directed graph in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things that might help (caveat: I do not know this gem well, and there may be better approaches)

- You need to add a require to make the method available: `require 'rgl/connected_components'`
- `each_connected_component` assumes an undirected graph, but you can convert a directed graph to an undirected one if necessary

The following code seems to do what you want:

```
require 'rgl/base'
require 'rgl/adjacency'
require 'rgl/connected_components'

g = RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph[1,2, 2,3, 4,5]

components = []

g.to_undirected.each_connected_component { |c| components <<  c }

p components

# => [[3, 2, 1], [5, 4]]
```